# Can you implicitly activate array member of union in a C++20 constexpr constructor?

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, unions

I'm using C++20 and have a structure that contains a transparent union that contains an array.  I need my structure to have a `constexpr` constructor, but I would like to avoid filling the entire array in the event that the constructor is not called in a `constexpr` context.  Gcc allows me to do this, while clang does not.

Here is a minimal example:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>

struct test {
  union {
    char buf_[15];
  };

  // Both gcc and clang accept:
  // constexpr test() : buf_{} { fillbuf(); }

  // Gcc accepts and clang rejects:
  constexpr test() { fillbuf(); }

  // Clang accepts and gcc rejects
  // constexpr test() {}

  constexpr void fillbuf() {
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated())
      std::fill_n(buf_, sizeof(buf_), 0);
  }
};

constinit test mytest{};
```

With the second constructor (the one I want), clang complains that my constructor is not `constexpr` because "assignment to member 'buf_' of union with no active member is not allowed in a constant expression."

Note that with the third constructor (commented out above), clang accepts the code while gcc (sensibly, I think) complains that "'test()' is not a constant expression because it refers to an incompletely initialized variable."

Which compiler is right?  Is there an alternative way to achieve what I need?  In many cases I only need the first byte of the buffer, so don't want the overhead of filling the whole thing when constructing an object in a non-`constexpr` context.

For what it's worth, I'm using gcc 13.2.1 and clang 16.0.6.

Comment: In general in C++ just stop using `union` it has quite a few pitfalls (active member and undefined behaviors), it is mainly kept around for backward compatibility with "C". Have a look at [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) instead.

Comment: @PepijnKramer How do you think `std::variant` is implemented?  You basically can't do that without unions (in part because of the strict aliasing rule.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can activate a trivial array union member in a constant expression just as normally at runtime with C++20.

The problem is that

```
std::fill_n(buf_, sizeof(buf_), 0);
```

can't activate any member. The only form of expression that can implicitly start the lifetime of objects like this is a built-in or trivial assignment expression whose left-hand is a (chain of) built-in member access and array index operations on an expression that nominates a union member. See [[class.union.general]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.union#general-6) for the details.

Because `fill_n` will however assign through a pointer to the union member, i.e. without naming the union member, it does not qualify for that special rule. Therefore it can't start the lifetime of a union member and can't make a union member active, whether at runtime or in a constant expression. The `fill_n` call has undefined behavior at runtime.

So, you can easily make the member active before the call to `fill_n` yourself by adding:

```
buf_[0] = 0 /* or anything else */;
```

or directly using a loop to assign to `buf_[i]` (not through a reference or pointer).

Clang follows this rule strictly, while GCC is being overly permissive.

Comment: Would `uninitialized_fill` work? This seems to be a legitimate use, but will it be acceptable at compile-time?

Comment: @Red.Wave No, it won't. `uninitialized_fill` places and starts the lifetime of individual array elements with `new`, but never starts the lifetime of the array object, so it is still has UB.

Answer (score -1):

[[expr.basic.lval]p11](https://wg21.link/basic.lval#11):

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue whose type is not similar to one of the following types, the behavior is undefined:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object, or
> - a `char`, `unsigned char`, or `std::byte` type.

So, `std::fill_n(buf_, sizeof(buf_), 0);` should set the object representation of `*this` to all zeroes without making `buf_` the active union member.